# .Net 4 causes DLLImport function to return failure code, .Net 2, 3 or 3.5 does not

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I am looking at a sample project from sourceforge for linking to a TSAPI (not TAPI) telephone system - http://tsapi.sourceforge.net/ .

My development environment is 32bit Windows XP and the project is set to target x86.

This works fine as provided to run against .Net 2 but I need to run against .Net 4.  When I change the framework and run the 1st function returns -1 indicating failure.

The function definition is:

```
[DllImport("csta32.dll")]
public static extern int acsOpenStream(ref UInt32 acsHandle, int invokeIDType, UInt32 invokeID, int streamType, char[] serverID, char[] loginID, char[] passwd, char[] applicationName, int acsLevelReq, char[] apiVer, ushort sendQSize, ushort sendExtraBufs, ushort recvQSize, ushort recvExtraBufs, ref PrivateData_t priv);
```

The c# code (extracted from sample project) for calling this function is:

```
    // The public method to open the ACS stream
    public bool open(string strLoginId, string strPasswd, string strServerId)
    {
        // Convert the parameters to character arrays
        char[] serverId = strServerId.ToCharArray();
        char[] loginId = strLoginId.ToCharArray();
        char[] passwd = strPasswd.ToCharArray();

        // Define the initial set of variables used for opening the ACS Stream
        int invokeIdType = 1;
        UInt32 invokeId = 0;
        int streamType = 1;
        char[] appName = "Mojo".ToCharArray();
        int acsLevelReq = 1;
        char[] apiVer = "TS1-2".ToCharArray();
        ushort sendQSize = 0;
        ushort sendExtraBufs = 0;
        ushort recvQSize = 0;
        ushort recvExtraBufs = 0;

        // Define the mandatory (but unused) private data structure
        Csta.PrivateData_t privData = new Csta.PrivateData_t();
        privData.vendor = "MERLIN                          ".ToCharArray();
        privData.length = 4;
        privData.data = "N".ToCharArray();

        // Define the event buffer pointer that gets data back from the TServer
        ushort numEvents = 0;
        Csta.EventBuf_t eventBuf = new Csta.EventBuf_t();
        ushort eventBufSize = (ushort)Csta.CSTA_MAX_HEAP;

        // Open the ACS stream
        try
        {
            int openStream = Csta.acsOpenStream(ref acsHandle, invokeIdType, invokeId, streamType, serverId, loginId, passwd, appName, acsLevelReq, apiVer, sendQSize, sendExtraBufs, recvQSize, recvExtraBufs, ref privData);
```

A C++ sample application is also provided in which the function call is:

```
m_nRetCode = acsOpenStream(&m_lAcsHandle            // Handle for ACS Stream 
    , APP_GEN_ID            // APP_GEN_ID indicates Application   generated invokeID's
    , (InvokeID_t)m_ulInvokeID  // By default 1
    , ST_CSTA
    , (ServerID_t *)(serverID)  // AE Server Name
    , (LoginID_t *)(loginID)    // CTI LoginID
    , (Passwd_t *)(password)  // CTI LoginID password
    , (AppName_t *)"TSAPI_AgentView"
    , ACS_LEVEL1
    , (Version_t *) "TS1-2" // private Data version in use 8 in our case
    , 10
    , 5 
    , 50
    , 5
    , (PrivateData_t *)&m_stPrivateData); // private Data.
```

If I change the DLLImport to

```
[DllImport("csta32.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int acsOpenStream(ref UInt32 acsHandle, int invokeIDType, UInt32 invokeID, int streamType, char[] serverID, char[] loginID, char[] passwd, char[] applicationName, int acsLevelReq, char[] apiVer, ushort sendQSize, ushort sendExtraBufs, ushort recvQSize, ushort recvExtraBufs, ref PrivateData_t priv);
```

I get the runtime error

PInvokeStackImbalance was detected
Message: A call to PInvoke function 'Mojo!Csta::acsOpenStream' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Avaya do not provide the header file  - the documentation indicates the function definition to be:

```
RetCode_t acsOpenStream(
ACSHandle_t *acsHandle, /* RETURN */
InvokeIDType_t invokeIDType, /* INPUT */
InvokeID_t invokeID, /* INPUT */
StreamType_t streamType, /* INPUT */
ServerID_t *serverID, /* INPUT */
LoginID_t *loginID, /* INPUT */
Passwd_t *passwd, /* INPUT */
AppName_t *applicationName, /* INPUT */
Level_t acsLevelReq /* INPUT */
Version_t *apiVer, /* INPUT */
unsigned short sendQSize, /* INPUT */
unsigned short sendExtraBufs, /* INPUT */
unsigned short recvQSize, /* INPUT */
unsigned short recvExtraBufs /* INPUT */
PrivateData_t *privateData); /* INPUT */
```

Comment: char[] looks wrong. Should be string surely. Anyway, you need to show the C++ declaration and the C# calling code.

Comment: The 23rd argument has the wrong value.

Comment: You still did not show the C++ declaration of the function. Anyway, ToCharArray won't produce a null-terminated string. You need to use string instead of char[]. And set the CharSet right. You code was always wrong, you just got lucky before I guess.

Comment: Why can't you show the C++ declaration? We can't help without that and I'm losing interest. With no solid information you will just continue to get bogus answers that lead you on wild goose chases.

Comment: There is a header file. You haven't found it yet. The C++ example uses it. I can only guess that the string parameters are really char*. In which case you need string instead of char[] in your C#. Do you understand the difference? This question is a real mess now. You need to start again probably. Try to get a good grip on what the function's definition is in C++ and strip out the spurious parts of the question.

Comment: The C++ code won't compile without a declaration for the function and the various types. For example, what is ServerID_t and so on? Until you know the interface for the function, you can't write the C# code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  - Thank you for your help - I have now resolved.  As I mentioned this is a SourceForge project which I only found on Thursday so its not my code.  But you are right - the char[] definitions should be string which fixes the problem.  I guess 2.0 handles this whilst 4.0 does not.

Comment: I could write that in an answer for you to accept?  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if that's allowed, yes - don't want to get kicked off after just 1 question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string parameters that you declared as `char[]` were always wrong. I guess you got away with that by chance in earlier .net versions.

The C++ code declares these parameters as `char*`, i.e. pointer to  null terminated character array. The correct way to declare these parameters in your C# code is as `string`. The p/invoke marshaller will take care of turning your C# strings into C strings and you can remove all the spurious `ToCharArray()` code.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are talking about 4.0, I *suppose*, also it's hard to deduct form the question provided, that application that you run under 4.0 is run also under 64bit OS.

If, so, the failure is absolutely justified, cause you're targeting `csta32.dll` DLL and 
use like parameters `UInt32`.

First steps to make forward the solution to fix this, are

- choose right library to import from
- substitude `Uint32` with `uint`, so the correct dimension for the type will be chosen by runtime.

But these are, naturally the tries, that should respect correct signature of the correct method that have to be declared to import.

If this is not what you are asking for, or it's not your problem, please clarify.

Comment: uint and UInt32 are both 32 bits wide on all platforms.

Comment: I am running on 32 bit XP and the platform target is x86.  As mentioned, the unusual part (to me) is that it works until you change the target framework, which would suggest that something has changed in how you should use DLLImport between 3.5 and 4.0 that I am not aware of.

Comment: And if you had suddenly switched to x64 then the DLL would have failed to load.

Comment: But I am not changing to x64?

Comment: @Rob No good in a comment! You need to edit the question to add this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to amend the char [] to string.  This then works on .Net 4.0 - if left as char [] it returns -2 ( ACSERR_BADPARAMETER ).

Therefore, 2.0 must handle this as this change is not required for the DLLImport to work on that version of the framework.